# Regex: Match words and special characters unless in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I've already had a look at other questions which are nearly identical, and with a little customization I've found a solution that works in [RegExr](http://regexr.com?32fd3). The problem is that it doesn't work in Javascript.

Expression: `([^\s]*"[^"]+"[^\s]*)|[^"]?\w+[^"]?`

Test string: `+w1 @w2 (w3 (w4) @"w5 6"`

Expected result: `['+w1', '@w2', '(w3', '(w4)', '@"w5 w6"']`

Javascript code: `console.log(/([^\s]*"[^"]+"[^\s]*)|[^"]?\w+[^"]?/g.exec(test_str));`

Javascript result: `["+w1 ", undefined]` (tested in FF15 and Chrome 22)

I've looked up documentation on the MDN, but there are no other relevant flags than the global flag. Just to try I've added multiline and case-insensitive flags, but they were no use.

Any idea what makes it break in Javascript while it seems to work in RegExr? (And isn't Flash' Actionscript also ECMAScript, so shouldn't RegExr use the same regex engine?) In RegExr, the only enabled flag is the global flag.

**Edit:** Another issue is that `"w1 \"w2\" w3"` will be matched as two words while it should be one word. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
console.log('+w1 @w2 (w3 (w4) @"w5 6"'.match(/[^"\s]+(?:".*"\S*)?/g));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Can you explain why it didn't work with `result = /regex/flags.exec(input)`?

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky Well I meant that it matches my original test string, unlike regexp.exec. I wonder why, the global flag should make it do the same.

Comment: @Luc If you use `exec`, you need to use a loop.

Comment: i dont see any reason for using regex for this since its a littlebit complicated. besides it would not work if i put @"foo bar" somewhere in the middle. i dont want to offend by writing this but i think a parser would be a better choice.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky The reason I wanted to use a regex is because it basically only has to split on spaces, except when inside quotation marks. Didn't seem that hard, but perhaps you're right. (And it's not offending to me at all.)

Comment: well if you basicly only want to split on spaces then all you need is this: string.split(/\s+/);

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky Well, the point is space in quotes should not be treated as a delimiter.

Comment: that is why i think regex is the wrong choice. the right choice is to use a parser. regex is a parser instruction but not powerfull enuf. at least not in javascript.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky Well it seems powerful alright, just becomes very complex compared to a parser.